# How to make an asymmetric multiplayer scene with ARcore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, unity3d-unet

I am doing research for my degree's final project because I want to make an asymmetric multiplayer game with Unity. One player has to use ARCore to see the scene from above and the other player is controlling a character from a FPS view, without ARCore.

I have read the [article](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2017/11/01/experimenting-with-multiplayer-arcore-and-arkit-jump-in-with-sample-code/) that introduces ARInterface and I have tested Unet with both smartphones and the connection works fine, but I don't know if it is possible to have in the same scene a player that does not use AR but interacts with the scene.

The flow of the game could be similar to the AR Tanks demo: First an AR Setup scene, then a lobby and finally the main scene.

Comment: How is the AR component even used here? That is, from a design perspective, why do you need ARCore at all? Asymmetry is fine, but what is the point of requiring an AR target if only one player needs it, what possible value is that adding?

Comment: The scene is a maze, the player with the first person perspective is trapped inside it and the one with ARcore is seeing the complete maze. The player with ARcore interacts with the maze to help the other player. Both players have to cooperate to win.

Comment: How does the FPS player's application know what maze he's in? I assume that's controlled by which AR target the overview player's app uses.